# Google Chrome Bookmarks Gone

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Google Chrome did an update or something and all of my bookmarks are gone.  Hours and hours of research gone.

I've tried restoring, but the restore file was "corrupted" and could not be retrieved.

There no longer seems to be an option to take the user data folder for Chrome and take it back to an earlier version.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: If the backup and the bookmark database is corrupt you are out of options.

Comment: Were you ever signed into Chrome with that account?